# I am getting mypy error when @property and @xxx.setter are defined in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I created a class as following.
It work perfectly when I execute the program.
However, when mypy is run, it gives me an error message.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name_template = name
        self.name2_template = name

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self.name_template

    @property
    def name2(self) -> str:
        return self.name2_template

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name_template: str):
        self.name_template = name_template

    @name2.setter
    def name2(self, name_template: str):
        self.name2_template = name_template
```

Error meesage

> "Callable[[Test], Any]" has no attribute "setter" error: Property

> "name" defined in "Test" is read-only

Python version is 3.8 and mypy version is 0.980.
Do you have any suggetion for these errors?

Comment: mypy currently requires you to defined `property` setters immediately after `property` getters. This is probably better practice anyway. Note, `pyright` actually has no problem with that. Also, you should definitely update your mypy version, since 0.980 is pretty out-of-date, and